# How do I "upgrade" to Windows 7 from Vista through Windows 8 with a volume license

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-vista, upgrade, volume-license

This is my situation. I have a computer lab of 23 machines (ACER Veriton M410) running Windows Vista business. We want to update the machines to Windows 7. The school was sold Windows 8 Pro on a Volume License deal and was told they would be able to downgrade to Windows 7.

Questions:

1. Can this be done?
2. If so, I believe I will need to acquire a Windows 7 Pro disk. If so, do I only need 1 copy of the disk?
3. Will I need to install Windows 8 before "upgrading"?

I'm familiar with installing Windows, but I'm pretty new to Volume Licensing and how to handle it. Any input is appreciated, including ways to speed the install process. There is no server/AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

1. Can this be done? **Yes**
2. If so, I believe I will need to acquire a Windows 7 Pro disk. If so, do I only need 1 copy of the disk? **You'll only need one copy.  You should be able to download the disk from Microsoft's Volume Licensing Service Center.**
3. Will I need to install Windows 8 before "upgrading"?  **No**

Detail:

You most definitely can use your Windows 8 Pro volume licenses to upgrade your machines from Windows Vista to Windows 7 Pro.  Technically what you will be doing is "downgrading" from Windows 8 Pro to Windows 7 Pro.

You should have (or soon will) receive an e-mail [sent to the e-mail address provided when the licenses were purchased] with instructions for logging into Microsoft's [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) where you will find your product keys and installation media.  On the VLSC site you'll be able to retrieve both Windows 8 Pro *and* Windows 7 Pro product keys.  It's likely you'll also be able to download Windows 7 Pro installation media.  Simply use the installation media to perform either an upgrade or clean installation (your choice) and provide your Windows 7 Pro product key when required.  No need to install Windows 8 on the machines first.

Comment: Marked as answer. Thank you for the help. I just got to make this attempt this week and your information is correct. That is a great relief. Now for some reason the install discs I made are not booting. Burned as .iso's, but the drive doesn't boot from them, though they can be read fine. But this will require a different question I'm afraid.